# Creating a new queue for every topic created by the user in the app

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My application uses Spring + RabbitMQ. It has already designed two features displaying user & his friend's posts on the home page & the notifications feature for any event which has happened.

For these two features I have predefined queues in the rabbitmq configuration bound to the exchanges. The underlying pattern is publish subscribe.

Now I am confused about the design of the third feature. Say a user creates a
a topic say "Halloween" & n users subscribe to it. Similarly n users will create their n topics & other users will subscribe to it for updates. This too is a pubsub pattern.

I believe for every individual topic a new queue should be created. So how do I dynamically create a queue for every topic created by the user in the application? Or there is some other way to deal with this?

Below is the existing queue configuration of the app.

```
<!-- Creates a queue for consumers to retrieve messages -->
<rabbit:queue name="UserPostpublishQueue" durable="true"/>

<!-- queue for sending notifications to users -->
<rabbit:queue name="notificationQueue" durable="true"/>

<!-- Fanout exchange for a pubsub bound to UserPostpublishQueue -->
<fanout-exchange name="broadcastPosts" durable="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit">
    <bindings>
        <binding queue="UserPostpublishQueue"/>
    </bindings>
</fanout-exchange>

<!-- Direct exchange for a broadcasting notifications -->
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="broadcastNotifications" durable="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit">
    <bindings>
        <binding queue="notificationQueue" key="notifications"/>
    </bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say a user creates a a topic say "Halloween" & n users subscribe to it [...] This too is a pubsub pattern.

while this is "publishing" of content, with other people "subscribing" to that content, this is not the pub-sub pattern.

the pub-sub pattern is explicitly about "toss it over the fence, who cares who is listening, if anyone". the pub-sub pattern is just a fancy term for what are typically events. It's the equivalent of someone saying "Hey! [thing] happened!" and other people responding in some way, if they feel like responding. if a specific person is not there to hear that the thing happened, then too bad. they don't get notice of that thing happening. it's like being out with friends. if one of your friends is not there, then they don't get to "be there" later, when they decide to. they have already missed the opportunity.

in your situation, you are describing a newspaper or print magazine. content is being published for other people to consume. a subscriber expects the articles and reports to be delivered to them at some point in the future. if they do not receive the info they were promised from the magazine or newspaper, they will be upset. they don't have to 'be there' in person when the events are happening. they are getting a report after things happen, and are guaranteed (to a degree) to receive the report.

> I believe for every individual topic a new queue should be created.

this is a very bad idea. you will very quickly run into severe performance problems with the size and complexity of your RabbitMQ configuration and instances. You'll end up with thousands upon thousands of queues that are rarely used, if they are used more than once.

worse, though, is that you will likely end up treating the queues as if they were a database. once you realize that you can't query a queue, or read the same message multiple times, things fall apart fast.

> So how do I dynamically create a queue for every topic created by the user in the application?

the short answer is: don't.

> Or there is some other way to deal with this?

a message queue is a great way to push data between processes. use messaging services for that.

what you want is database design, where you keep track of who is subscribed to what content, etc.

all of this is following along the lines of things i have written:

- [how to do user notifications from RabbitMQ](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/)
- [the selective consumer anti-pattern](http://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/)

Comment: So Derick if we save everything only in the db wouldn't that put additional load on the db, instead of polling the queue the application will poll the db for any new data added. I understand queue is not the database. How about I persist the data in the db & also have a common or a centralized queue for the latest data, if there are any new posts it will definitely push to the user without the need to poll the db. And we can always purge the old data from the queue.